# Issue with Antd React Table Refresh Animation Causing Visual Discomfort

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I have a problem with the Antd React table component. I am using a socket to receive information dynamically, so I update the information in a useState hook to update the dataSource of the table within a 1-second timeout. The problem is that these refreshes have an animation in the table, causing a white hover effect every second. This creates a "blinking" effect that is visually uncomfortable. Also, a Checkbox component in one of the columns is affected because it is difficult to click on it due to the refresh effect of the table data. Sometimes the click event of that checkbox is not loaded.

Summary: My main problem is that when the data updates dynamically every second, it creates an odd hover effect with each table refresh.

I would greatly appreciate any ideas you can provide to control or eliminate this effect. Thank you very much!

My apologies, as I am new to React and Antd, and I apologize for any mistakes in my English.

I have tried visually removing the hover effect, but it doesn't work as there is still a slight visual refresh effect. Is this a limitation of the Antd table or something that cannot be achieved using Antd?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.